# Cronjob only once at a specific time symfony php

Tags: php, symfony, cron

I’m working on a symfony project and I need to execute a task only once at a specific time(for example at 23/06/2022 18:30)
What’s the best way to do that

Is using the crontab a good idea in this case ?

Comment: You only want to execute it once ever? `at` would be the command you want to use for that, not the cron, which is for recurring tasks.

Answer (score 1):

if I understand correctly you want to run an action only once, it's best to do a command and run it manually, if you want to schedule it to run automatically, you can use cron for this purpose, e.g. 30 18 23 06 * php path_of_your_project/bin/console your:command